# A Mathematica analog to drawing an ellipse in AutoCAD

Tags: geographics

My real name is Wilhelm Doofenschmirtz. While my cousin is busy taking over the tri-state area, I am attempting Illinois. What I am trying to do is figure out an easy way to make an ellipse over a map, where it will show the scaled width and height of an ellipse when I expand/shrink it over a map.  This will help me plan my conquest.

I tried doing 'drawing tools', since it lets me make an ellipse and get coordinates. I could not figure out how to have it do both, let alone change the coordinates to show the width and height. I can do get the correct coordinates if I use 'get coordinates' over a parametric plot of an ellipse, but I lose the ability to expand/shrink.

I could also use 'Manipulate', but that doesn't seem to be an aesthetically pleasing route to show my currently nonexistent army for morale. So, I am open to suggestions and help. I do not care if the ellipse goes past the borders, as I might feel extra ambitious in the future.

[image: Maps of Illinois]

Comment: Do you want the width and height of the ellipse to correspond to some unit?

Comment: Ideally yes, either km or miles.

Comment: "make an ellipse over a map" - I'm assuming your map is equirectangularly projected? It won't exactly be an ellipse if you switch to, say, Mercator.

Comment: @J.M. yes, I am treating it Cartesian.

Comment: I found out about [Locator](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locator.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike [`Circle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle.html), [`GeoCircle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoCircle.html) can't draw ellipses directly on maps (!)

So, here is a way to do what i guess you need :

```
ellipse[{{a_, b_}, deg_}] := 
 Table[{Norm[
    RotationTransform[
      deg*Pi/180.]@(Sqrt[(b^2/(1 - ((1 - (b/a)^2)*Cos[t]^2)))]*{Cos[
         t], Sin[t]})], -deg + t*180./Pi}, {t, 0, 2*Pi, 2.*Pi/(2*34)}]
```

then

```
gd = Quiet@
     GeoDestination[
      Entity["City", {"Champaign", "Illinois", 
        "UnitedStates"}], #] & /@ ellipse[{10000*{4, 2}, 30}];


GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["StreetMap"], 
  Polygon@Entity[
    "AdministrativeDivision", {"Illinois", "UnitedStates"}],
  {Blue, Thickness[0.01], Line[gd], Red, PointSize[0.03], 
   Point@Entity["City", {"Champaign", "Illinois", "UnitedStates"}]} },
  GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 400]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about Geocircle or any of the geography stuff. I am looking through a lot of it right now.